# How to create InputStream from string in Vala

Tags: vala, gio

Given a string named **command**, I need to create GLib **InputStream** object **How**? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string command = "foobar";
GLib.InputStream input_stream = new GLib.MemoryInputStream.from_data (command.data, GLib.g_free);
```

Comment: The GLib.g_free call wasn't even what I was looking for, but the better find